# Logon/authentication is stucked, window.fbAsyncInit / FB.init does not appear to be running

Tags: authentication, facebook-authentication

since last few days when I try to login to my Facebook app (Lovedot) I cannot go past Facebook authentication. Well sometimes authentication works sometimes I need to refresh few times and sometimes even refresh does not help.

I noticed same issue when I try to connect to TopEleven game.

Code that I use is:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 960, height: 2000 });

        FB.init({ appId: 'MYAPPID', channelUrl: '//fb.lovedot.com/channel.html', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                window.location = 'https://fb.lovedot.com/outFacebookLanding.aspx?';
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
        });
```

So basically this is copy-paste that I found on Facebook.
When I check HTTP Watch trace I see:

- ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET when accessing https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
- Request to https://1-pct.channel.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_MYUSERID&seq=25&partition=246&clientid=1a0bc541&cb=jhp8&idle=21&state=active takes 30 seconds and this is request is repeating and again taking 30 seconds.

This started to happen approx. in last 3-4 days.

Any idea?

Comment: are you calling from https ?

Comment: Somehow I have impression that it works better early in the morning European time and not so good in the evening.